# How to transfer a New Zealand driver's license for a Victorian state license in Australia?

Tags: driving-license, australia, new-zealand-citizens

When you move to Australia as a New Zealand citizen, you're allowed to drive for a while on your NZ license (time depends on state).  In Victoria, how do you change to an Australian license?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this a few weeks back, and the process was frustrating but reasonably straight forward.  It just takes time.

First step is to get a Certificate of Particulars from New Zealand police.  This costs NZ$11 and takes a few business days, but can be done over the phone and they'll email it. It's best to do this before booking an appointment with VicRoads in case it takes longer than expected.

Next is to book an appointment with VicRoads. It costs around $75, and you'll choose your nearest center and book a time to attend. They're really strict, so don't be late.  You'll need to bring:

- Your New Zealand license
- proof of address in Australia
- certificate of particulars
- another proof of ID (eg NZ passport) (although not everyone I know has been asked for the second one)

At the appointment you'll fill out a form with the help of staff, take a quick eye test, get a photo taken and be issued with a temporary license. The full one will arrive in the mail within a couple of weeks.

Note that if you have any medical conditions, or take medication on a daily basis, you may be required to get a letter from a doctor indicating that you're ok to drive.